# For Loop with counter in PHP not working properly on Submit

Tags: php, for-loop

I have a very weird problem. I have a table that is being populated from the database. To each row, I have added a checkbox and a textbox. When the user clicks the checkbox, the texbox is displayed. When I try to get these values on submit, very strangely when I check the 1st or 2nd row the values are returned normally. When I exclude the 1st and 2nd row, they don't get saved properly.

> **My PHP Code**

```
<?PHP
    $myquery="  select A,B,C,Row_Number from Test WHERE Serial_Number='$Serial_Number';
    $fetched=sqlsrv_query($conn,$myquery) ; 
    if( $fetched === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));}
    while($res=sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetched,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
    {
        $Row_Number=$res['Row_Number'];
        echo "<tr><td>".$res['A']."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$res['B']."</td></tr>";
        echo "<tr><td>".$res['C']."</td>";
        echo "<td style='width:2%;'><input type='checkbox' name='tick[]' value='".$Row_Number."' onClick='document.getElementById('comments').focus();' id='Chk_".$Row_Number."'></td>";
        echo "<td style='display:none;' id='Chk_".$Row_Number."_box'><input type='text' name='reason[]' id='comments' class='form-control'></td></tr>";
    }
?>

<script>
    $(function(){
    $("input[type='checkbox']").change(function(){
    if($(this).is(":checked"))
    {
       $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_box").show();
    }
    else{                     $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_box").find("input[type='text']").val("")  ;
    $("#"+$(this).attr("id")+"_box").hide(); 
    }
    });
    });
</script>
```

> **Code on Submit**

```
for($i=0;$i<count($_POST['reason']);$i++)
{
echo $_POST['reason'][$i];
echo $_POST['tick'][$i];
}
```

> **Results when I check all the boxes :**

[image]

> **Results when I check all the other boxes except the first 2**

[image]

and I get an error saying **Undefined offset** in the php error logs.

I tried changing the for count from `count($_POST['reason'])` to `count($_POST['reason'])` and removing the `<br/>` in the echo, but yet get the same result. Where am I missing out or going wrong? Appreciate any suggestion. Thanks :)

Comment: echo count($_POST['reason']); what u get?

Comment: is it typo???     `$myquery="  select A,B,C,Row_Number from Test WHERE Serial_Number='$Serial_Number'` missing semi colon at end.

Comment: @devpro Thanks :) that was a typo.. corrected it.. Tried echoing countt($_POST['reason']); and get 4, when I have only checked 2 boxes..

Comment: echo count($_POST['reason']); getting count??

Comment: @devpro Tried echoing `count($_POST['reason']);` and get 4, when I have only checked 2 boxes..

Comment: it means, count is 4 with array(1,1,0,0);

Comment: print_r($_POST['reason']); chk

Comment: @devpro : `4 Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Test [3] => Test )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104501/discussion-between-devpro-and-sr1092).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[**From the chat:**](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/104501/discussion-between-devpro-and-sr1092)

you are getting empty values in `$_POST['reason']` array as:

```
Array ( [0] => [1] => [2] => Test [3] => Test )
```

Count of array should be **4** in this case (`2 empty and 2 filled = 4`).

You can solve this issue by using `array_filter()` and `array_values()`:

**Example:**

```
$reason = array_values(array_filter($_POST['reason']));
for($i=0;$i<count($reason);$i++)
{
echo $reason[$i];
echo $_POST['tick'][$i];
}
```

[array_filter()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) for removing empty values.
[array_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) for reorder the keys

Answer (score 0):

try below code

```
<?php
  $myquery = "select A,B,C,Row_Number from Test WHERE Serial_Number=".$Serial_Number;
  $fetched = sqlsrv_query($conn,$myquery); 
  if( $fetched === false ) { die( print_r( sqlsrv_errors(), true ));}
  while($res = sqlsrv_fetch_array($fetched,SQLSRV_FETCH_ASSOC))
  {
    $Row_Number = $res['Row_Number'];
    echo "<tr><td>".$res['A']."</td>";
    echo "<td>".$res['B']."</td></tr>";
    echo "<tr><td>".$res['C']."</td>";
    echo "<td style='width:2%;'><input type='checkbox' name='tick[]' value='".$Row_Number."' onClick='document.getElementById('comments').focus();' id='Chk_".$Row_Number."'></td>";
    echo "<td style='display:none;' id='Chk_".$Row_Number."_box'><input type='text' name='reason[]' id='comments' class='form-control'></td></tr>";
  }
?>
```

Comment: my friend, it was the typo error, check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35619879/for-loop-with-counter-in-php-not-working-properly-on-submit/35620489#35620489